# What does list[nextlight] do in this code?

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this code for a few weeks and I asked my teacher for help and he added this line `firstlight.src = list[nextlight];` which made it all work. He explained it to me but I just didn;t get the point and how it worked. Can someone explain to me why we equal the source image to list[nextlight]?

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  

  <h1>JavaScript Code</h1> 
  <p>Traffic Light</p> 

<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="ChangeLight()">Change Light</button>  



  <script> 
    var list = ["only red1.jpg","red-yellow 2.jpg", "green3.jpg","yellowonly4.jpg"];
    var nextlight = 0;
    function ChangeLight() {
      nextlight = nextlight + 1;      
      if (nextlight == list.length) 
        nextlight = 0;      
      var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');     
      firstlight.src = list[nextlight]; 
    } 
  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What precisely about that is confusing you? Do you know what the value of `nextlight` is? What indexing into an array does?

Comment: What does the light behavior tell you when you execute this code? What sequence do the lights go in? And how does that relate to the items in `list`? If you think about those things, you can figure out what's happening yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
firstlight.src = list[nextlight];
```

sets the src attribute of the image element to the next image in the list. It is effectively equivalent to

```
<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg"/> <!-- after the first click -->
<img id="traffic" src="red-yellow 2.jpg" /> <!-- after the second click -->
<!-- and so on.. -->
```

This works because you have images named exactly what is contained in the `list[]` array in the same working directory as the webpage itself; `nextlight` is the *number* or position of the next image of the traffic light in your `list`:

```
list[0] == "only red1.jpg", list[1] == "red-yellow 2.jpg", // and so on because..
nextlight == 0,             nextlight == 1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a global variable called `nextLight` which is equal to `0`. Upon the button click the function increments this number so `nextLight` is `1`.

Then it checks if the new number is equal to the length of the list. *If* it is equal that means that the *first image should be selected again*.

Why? Because arrays in JavaScipt has a 0-base index which means an array of 4 elements has the length of 4 but the last index `3` since it starts at 0, 1, 2, 3.

It then for each click it changes the `src` of the image (`firstlight.src = list[nextlight]`) with each respective url at `list[0]`, `list[1]`, `list[2]`, `list[3]` and when it reaches index 4 it resets to `list[0]` again.

Comment: so list[nextlight] acts like a loop of my array?

Comment: @Joseph.JJ It acts as the current position in the loop